# SUM with a pivot to calculate overall score

Tags: mysql, sum, pivot, pivot-table, myisam

From another question I got this query to get my scores summed up properly:

```
SELECT callSign,event, SUM(score) 
  FROM scores LEFT JOIN candidates 
ON scores.candidateID=candidates.id 
  WHERE candidateID IN 
    (SELECT id 
      FROM candidates 
    WHERE assessmentID='1321') 
  GROUP BY event, callSign
  ORDER BY candidateID,event
```

I get data that looks like:

```
callSign    event           TotalScore
Y209    Bridge                  45
Y209    PSA                     3
Y209    Team Analyst Exam       40
X125    PSA                     1
X125    Team Analyst Exam       38
V023    Amazing Race Planning   37
```

What I need is data like:

```
callSign      Bridge   PSA   Amazing Race Planning     Team Analyst Exam   
V023                                37
Y209           45       3                                   40         
X125                    1                                   38
```

**TABLE STRUCTURE**

```
`events`
id  event
1   PSA
2   Bridge
30  Stress Board
25  Amazing Race Planning
26  Amazing Race Execution

`scores`
id  candidateID     event            rubric            category                         score   comment
1   18       Team Analyst Exam  Team Leader Rubric  Organizes and Tasks Team Members    3    
2   18       Team Analyst Exam  Team Leader Rubric  Roles and Responsibilities          5    
3   18       Team Analyst Exam  Team Leader Rubric  Backward Planning                   5    
4   18       Team Analyst Exam  Team Leader Rubric  Time Management

`candidates`    
id  firstName   middleInitial   lastName    callSign    service     rank    sex     height  weight  assessmentID    currentlyAssessing  hired
```

callSign is where X125 would go

Comment: looks like @bluefeet beat me to it.

Comment: Your subquery is unnecessary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using MySQL, in order to pivot the data into columns, you will need to use an aggregate function with a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT callSign, 
    SUM(case when event = 'Bridge' then score else 0 end) as Bridge,
    SUM(case when event = 'PSA' then score else 0 end) as PSA,
    SUM(case when event = 'Amazing Race Planning' then score else 0 end) As AmazingRacePlanning,
    SUM(case when event = 'Team Analyst Exam' then score else 0 end) as TeamAnalystExam
FROM scores 
LEFT JOIN candidates 
    ON scores.candidateID=candidates.id 
WHERE candidateID IN (SELECT id 
                      FROM candidates 
                      WHERE assessmentID='1321') 
GROUP BY callSign
```

If you have an unknown number of `events`, then you will have to use a prepared statement to generate dynamic SQL:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN event = ''',
      event,
      ''' THEN score END) AS `',
      event, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM scores 
LEFT JOIN candidates 
    ON scores.candidateID=candidates.id;


SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT callSign, ', @sql, ' 
           FROM scores 
            LEFT JOIN candidates 
                ON scores.candidateID=candidates.id 
            WHERE candidateID IN (SELECT id 
                                  FROM candidates 
                                  WHERE assessmentID=''1321'') 
            GROUP BY callSign');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

Edit #1, if your `events` are stored in a separate table, then you can use the following to generate the dynamic result:

```
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
    CONCAT(
      'sum(CASE WHEN event = ''',
      event,
      ''' THEN score END) AS `',
      event, '`'
    )
  ) INTO @sql
FROM events;



SET @sql 
  = CONCAT('SELECT callSign, ', @sql, ' 
           FROM scores 
            LEFT JOIN candidates 
                ON scores.candidateID=candidates.id 
            WHERE candidateID IN (SELECT id 
                                  FROM candidates 
                                  WHERE assessmentID=''1321'') 
            GROUP BY callSign');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/89fa9/1)

Comment: thanks, now what if i have a table called `events` that has a list of the events i need to aggregate? `SELECT event FROM events ORDER BY id`. Could I work that in to the query so I dont have to statically add events as they come and go?

Comment: @h3rrmiller See my edit. If you are going to have an unknown number of `events` then you will need to use dynamic sql to generate the sql string.  If you would update your OP with your table structures, sample data, then I could show you exactly how this will work.

Comment: @h3rrmiller I see you edited your post with the `scores` and `events` table but you did not include the `candidates` table, can you add that?

Comment: done, i left out examples because they are names but i think the column names are pretty obvious

Comment: @h3rrmiller See my edit, I included a dynamic version that will pull the `events` from the separate table.

Comment: that is awesome... thank you so much.  Is this something that will work with php?  Ive never used a prepared statement with php.